# Assist With Flickering/Glitching pixels with 8086 assembler TASM project

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

i have created a virtual piano able to play a full octave (with options to raise the octave twice with + and -), but my problem is not with the audio, its with the graphics. my program is running a graphic proc that basically  paints the white square, paints the black lines to separate the notes and then prints the small letters to help the user know what letter activates what key, and the black notes themselves. after I finished the with pure graphic part, I started working on the RecieveKey proc, I finished writing the proc and everything is working, u can activate all 8 white notes with letter S-L and all black notes with E,R,Y,U,I. but I am experiencing a VERY annoying "bug". after the key is pressed on the keyboard, the note turns gray and after 0.746 seconds it turns back white. but there is this flickering/glitching weird issue I cant seem to solve. i will paste the full code here, can anyone PLEASE help me understand why this is happening?

```
; Play white keys with S,D,F,G,H,J,K,Left
; Play black keys with E,R,Y,U,I
; Go up octave with +
; Go down octave with -
; Press ESC to end
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
    x dw 0; position of X
    y dw 0; position of Y
    color1 dw 00007h ; Gray
    color3 dw 0000h; Black Color
    CorrentOctave db 31h; Starts at Octave n1:
    Linex dw 0; position of X of line
    Column db 0; Position of Column
    Row db 0; Position of Row
    Letter db 0; Letter
; --------------------------
CODESEG
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proc Graphic
    xor ax,ax
    xor dx,dx
    xor cx,cx
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h     ;Moving to graphic mode
    call PrintWhite
    call PrintBlackLines
    call PrintLetterNotes
    call PrintBlackKeys
    call PrintFix
    call PrintCorrentOctave

    ret
endp Graphic
; --------------------------
proc PrintPixel ;This procedure Receives parameters of x and y and a colour and prints a pixel on the screen
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push cx
    mov ax, [bp+4]  ;Colour of the pixel
    mov dx, [bp+6]  ;Y parameter of the pixel
    mov cx, [bp+8]  ;X parameter of the pixel
    mov bh, 0h      ;Page, should be 0
    mov ah, 0ch
    int 10h         ;Pixel draw interrupt
    pop cx
    pop bp
    ret 6
endp PrintPixel
; --------------------------
proc PrintWhite ;This procedure prints a 120x320 white rectangle
    mov [x],0
    mov [y],50
PrintLine1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push 0000Fh; White Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],320
    jne PrintLine2
    cmp [y],170
    jne PrintLine3
    ret
PrintLine2:
    inc [x]
    jmp PrintLine1
PrintLine3:
    mov [x],0
    inc [y]
    jmp PrintLine1
    
endp PrintWhite
; --------------------------
proc PrintBlackLines ;This procedure will print the black lines seperating the white keys every 20 pixels.
    mov [Linex],40
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],80
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],120
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],160
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],200
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],240
    call PrintBlackLine1
    mov [Linex],280
    call PrintBlackLine1
endp PrintBlackLines

proc PrintBlackLine1 ; this procedure will print the first black line seperating keys.
    mov ax,[Linex]
    mov [x], ax
    mov [y],50
FirstBlack1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push 0000h; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [y],170
    jne FirstBlack2
    ret
FirstBlack2:
    inc [y]
    jmp FirstBlack1
endp PrintBlackLine1
; --------------------------
; --------------------------
proc PrintBlackKeys; this procedure will print all the 6 black keys on the piano
    call PrintBlackKey1
    call PrintBlackKey2
    call PrintBlackKey3
    call PrintBlackKey4
    call PrintBlackKey5
endp PrintBlackKeys

proc PrintBlackKey1; this procedure will print the first black key.
    mov [x],30
    mov [y],50
FirstBlackKey1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color3]; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],45
    jne FirstBlackKey2
    cmp [y],110
    jne FirstBlackKey3
    ret
FirstBlackKey2:
    inc [x]
    jmp FirstBlackKey1
FirstBlackKey3:
    mov [x],30
    inc [y]
    jmp FirstBlackKey1
endp PrintBlackKey1

proc PrintBlackKey2; this procedure will print the Second black key.
    mov [x],70
    mov [y],50
SecondBlackKey1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color3]; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],85
    jne SecondBlackKey2
    cmp [y],110
    jne SecondBlackKey3
    ret
SecondBlackKey2:
    inc [x]
    jmp SecondBlackKey1
SecondBlackKey3:
    mov [x],70
    inc [y]
    jmp SecondBlackKey1
endp PrintBlackKey2

proc PrintBlackKey3; this procedure will print the third black key.
    mov [x],150
    mov [y],50
ThirdBlackKey1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color3]; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],165
    jne ThirdBlackKey2
    cmp [y],110
    jne ThirdBlackKey3
    ret
ThirdBlackKey2:
    inc [x]
    jmp ThirdBlackKey1
ThirdBlackKey3:
    mov [x],150
    inc [y]
    jmp ThirdBlackKey1
endp PrintBlackKey3

proc PrintBlackKey4; this procedure will print the Fourth black key.
    mov [x],190
    mov [y],50
ForthBlackKey1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color3]; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],205
    jne ForthBlackKey2
    cmp [y],110
    jne ForthBlackKey3
    ret
ForthBlackKey2:
    inc [x]
    jmp ForthBlackKey1
ForthBlackKey3:
    mov [x],190
    inc [y]
    jmp ForthBlackKey1
endp PrintBlackKey4

proc PrintBlackKey5; this procedure will print the Fifth black key.
    mov [x],230
    mov [y],50
FifthBlackKey1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color3]; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],245
    jne FifthBlackKey2
    cmp [y],110
    jne FifthBlackKey3
    ret
FifthBlackKey2:
    inc [x]
    jmp FifthBlackKey1
FifthBlackKey3:
    mov [x],230
    inc [y]
    jmp FifthBlackKey1
endp PrintBlackKey5
; -------------------------
proc PrintFix
    mov [x],0
    mov [y],171
PrintFix1:
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push 0000h; Black Color
    call PrintPixel
    ret
endp PrintFix
; --------------------------
proc PrintLetterNotes ; this procedure will print a letter on each note so the user can know which key in the keyboard activates each note
    mov [Column],2
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],53h
    call PrintLetter ; Letter S
    mov [Column],7
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],44h ; Letter D
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],12
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],46h ; Letter F
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],17
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],47h ; Letter G
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],22
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],48h ; Letter H
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],27
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],4Ah ; Letter J
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],32
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],4Bh ; Letter K
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],37
    mov [Row],22
    mov [Letter],4Ch ; Letter L
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],4
    mov [Row],5
    mov [Letter],45h ; Letter E
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],9
    mov [Row],5
    mov [Letter],52h ; Letter R
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],19
    mov [Row],5
    mov [Letter],59h ; Letter Y
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],24
    mov [Row],5
    mov [Letter],55h ; Letter U
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],29
    mov [Row],5
    mov [Letter],49h ; Letter I
    call PrintLetter
        mov [Column],2
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],4Fh ; Letter O
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],3
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],63h ; Letter c
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],4
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],74h ; Letter t
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],5
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],61h ; Letter a
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],6
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],76h ; Letter v
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],7
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],65h ; Letter e
    call PrintLetter
    mov [Column],8
    mov [Row],2
    mov [Letter],3Ah ; Char :
    call PrintLetter
    ret
endp PrintLetterNotes
; --------------------------
proc PrintLetter ; prints letter 
    mov  dl, [Column]   ;Column
    mov  dh, [Row]   ;Row
    mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
    mov  ah, 02h  ;SetCursorPosition
    int  10h

    mov  al, [Letter]
    mov  bl, 000Fh  ;Color is White
    mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
    mov  ah, 0Eh  ;Teletype
    int  10h
    ret
endp PrintLetter
; ------------------------
proc PrintCorrentOctave
    mov  dl, 9  ;Column
    mov  dh, 2   ;Row
    mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
    mov  ah, 02h  ;SetCursorPosition
    int  10h

    mov  al, [CorrentOctave]
    mov  bl, 000Fh  ;Color is White
    mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
    mov  ah, 0Eh  ;Teletype
    int  10h
    ret
endp PrintCorrentOctave
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proc ReceiveKey ;This procedure Receives a key from the keyboard and matches it to a note
ReceiveKey: 
    
    mov ah,0
    Int 16h
    cmp al, 73h                 ;S on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je FirstWhiteKey
    cmp al, 64h                 ;D on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je SecondWhiteKey
    cmp al, 66h                 ;F on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je ThirdWhiteKey
    cmp al, 67h                 ;G on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je FourthWhiteKey
    cmp al, 68h                 ;H on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je FifthWhiteKey
    cmp al, 6Ah                 ;J on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je SixthWhiteKey
    cmp al, 6Bh                 ;K on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je SeventhWhiteKey
    cmp al, 6Ch                 ;L on the keyboard (WHITE)
    je EighthWhiteKey
    cmp al, 65h                 ;E on the keyboard (BLACK)
    je FirstBlackKey
    cmp al, 72h                 ;R on the keyboard (BLACK)
    je SecondBlackKey
    cmp al, 79h                 ;Y on the keyboard (BLACK)
    je ThirdBlackKey
    cmp al, 75h                 ;U on the keyboard (BLACK)
    je FourthBlackKey
    cmp al, 69h                 ;I on the keyboard (BLACK)
    je FifthBlackKey
    cmp al, 2Dh           ;Arrow Left on the keyboard (octave Dec)
    je OctaveDec
    cmp al, 3Dh              ;Arrow Right on the keyboard (octave inc)
    je OctaveInc
    cmp al, 1Bh                 ;ESC on the keyboard (CLOSE)
    je EndOfProc
    
    
    jmp ReceiveKey

FirstWhiteKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call FirstWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
SecondWhiteKey:
    ;call SecondWhiteKeyMusic
    call SecondWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
    
ThirdWhiteKey:
    ;call SecondWhiteKeyMusic
    call ThirdWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey

FourthWhiteKey:
    ;call FourthWhiteKeyMusic
    call FourthWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey

FifthWhiteKey:
    ;call FourthWhiteKeyMusic
    call FifthWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
    
SixthWhiteKey:
    ;call FourthWhiteKeyMusic
    call SixthWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey

SeventhWhiteKey:
    ;call FourthWhiteKeyMusic
    call SeventhWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
    
EighthWhiteKey:
    ;call FourthWhiteKeyMusic
    call EighthWhiteKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
FirstBlackKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call FirstBlackKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
SecondBlackKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call SecondBlackKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
ThirdBlackKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call ThirdBlackKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
FourthBlackKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call FourthBlackKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
FifthBlackKey:
    ;call FirstWhiteKeyMusic
    call FifthBlackKeyPaint 
    jmp ReceiveKey
    
EndOfProc:
    jmp exit
    
endp ReceiveKey
; --------------------------
proc OctaveInc
    cmp [CorrentOctave],33h
    jne OctaveInc1
    jmp ReceiveKey
OctaveInc1:
    inc [CorrentOctave]
    call PrintCorrentOctave
    jmp ReceiveKey
endp OctaveInc

proc OctaveDec
    cmp [CorrentOctave],31h
    jne OctaveDec1
    jmp ReceiveKey
OctaveDec1:
    dec [CorrentOctave]
    call PrintCorrentOctave
    jmp ReceiveKey
endp OctaveDec
; --------------------------
proc FirstWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the first white key in gray 
    mov [x],0
    mov [y],50
FirstWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the first white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],29
    jne FirstWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne FirstWhiteBig2
    mov [x],30
    mov [y],111
    jmp FirstWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FirstWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FirstWhiteKeyPaintBig
FirstWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],0
    jmp FirstWhiteKeyPaintBig
FirstWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the first white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],39
    jne FirstWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],170
    jne FirstWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite1
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite1:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call FirstWhiteKeyPaint
    
FirstWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FirstWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FirstWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],30
    jmp FirstWhiteKeyPaintSmall
    
endp FirstWhiteKeyPaint
; --------------------------
proc SecondWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Second white key in gray 
    mov [x],41
    mov [y],111
SecondWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Second white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],79
    jne SecondWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne SecondWhiteBig2
    mov [x],46
    mov [y],50
    jmp SecondWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SecondWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp SecondWhiteKeyPaintBig
SecondWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],41
    jmp SecondWhiteKeyPaintBig
SecondWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Second white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],69
    jne SecondWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],111
    jne SecondWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite2
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite2:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call SecondWhiteKeyPaint
SecondWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp SecondWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SecondWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],46
    jmp SecondWhiteKeyPaintSmall
endp SecondWhiteKeyPaint
; --------------------------
proc ThirdWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Third white key in gray 
    mov [x],81
    mov [y],111
ThirdWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Third white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],119
    jne ThirdWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne ThirdWhiteBig2
    mov [x],86
    mov [y],50
    jmp ThirdWhiteKeyPaintSmall
ThirdWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp ThirdWhiteKeyPaintBig
ThirdWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],81
    jmp ThirdWhiteKeyPaintBig
    
ThirdWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Third white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],119
    jne ThirdWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],110
    jne ThirdWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite3
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite3:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call ThirdWhiteKeyPaint
ThirdWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp ThirdWhiteKeyPaintSmall
ThirdWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],86
    jmp ThirdWhiteKeyPaintSmall
endp ThirdWhiteKeyPaint;
; -------------------------

proc FourthWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Fourth white key in gray 
    mov [x],121
    mov [y],50
FourthWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Fourth white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],149
    jne FourthWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne FourthWhiteBig2
    mov [x],149
    mov [y],111
    jmp FourthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FourthWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FourthWhiteKeyPaintBig
FourthWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],121
    jmp FourthWhiteKeyPaintBig
FourthWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Fourth white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],159
    jne FourthWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],170
    jne FourthWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite4
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite4:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call FourthWhiteKeyPaint
    
FourthWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FourthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FourthWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],121
    jmp FourthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
    
endp FourthWhiteKeyPaint
; --------------------------
proc FifthWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Fifth white key in gray 
    mov [x],161
    mov [y],111
FifthWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Fifth white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],199
    jne FifthWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne FifthWhiteBig2
    mov [x],166
    mov [y],50
    jmp FifthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FifthWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FifthWhiteKeyPaintBig
FifthWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],161
    jmp FifthWhiteKeyPaintBig
FifthWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Fifth white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],189
    jne FifthWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],111
    jne FifthWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite5
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite5:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call FifthWhiteKeyPaint
FifthWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp FifthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
FifthWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],166
    jmp FifthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
endp FifthWhiteKeyPaint

; --------------------------
proc SixthWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Sixth white key in gray 
    mov [x],201
    mov [y],111
SixthWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Sixth white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],239
    jne SixthWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne SixthWhiteBig2
    mov [x],206
    mov [y],50
    jmp SixthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SixthWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp SixthWhiteKeyPaintBig
SixthWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],201
    jmp SixthWhiteKeyPaintBig
SixthWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Sixth white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],229
    jne SixthWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],111
    jne SixthWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite6
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite6:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call SixthWhiteKeyPaint
SixthWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x]
    jmp SixthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SixthWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],206
    jmp SixthWhiteKeyPaintSmall
endp SixthWhiteKeyPaint
; --------------------------
proc SeventhWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Seventh white key in gray 
    mov [x],246
    mov [y],50
SeventhWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Seventh white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],279
    jne SeventhWhiteBig1
    cmp [y],170
    jne SeventhWhiteBig2
    mov [x],241
    mov [y],111
    jmp SeventhWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SeventhWhiteBig1:
    inc [x]
    jmp SeventhWhiteKeyPaintBig
SeventhWhiteBig2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],246
    jmp SeventhWhiteKeyPaintBig
    
SeventhWhiteKeyPaintSmall: ;Paints the small rectangle on the Seventh white key gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],246
    jne SeventhWhiteSmall1
    cmp [y],170
    jne SeventhWhiteSmall2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite7
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite7:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call SeventhWhiteKeyPaint
SeventhWhiteSmall1:
    inc [x] 
    jmp SeventhWhiteKeyPaintSmall
SeventhWhiteSmall2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],241
    jmp SeventhWhiteKeyPaintSmall
endp SeventhWhiteKeyPaint;
; --------------------------

proc EighthWhiteKeyPaint ; paints the Eighth white key in gray 
    mov [x],281
    mov [y],50
EighthWhiteKeyPaintBig: ;paints the big rectangle on the Seventh white key in gray
    push [x]
    push [y]
    push [color1]
    call PrintPixel
    cmp [x],319
    jne EighthWhite1
    cmp [y],170
    jne EighthWhite2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color1],00007h
    je ChangeToWhite8
    mov [color1],00007h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToWhite8:
    mov [color1],0000Fh
    call EighthWhiteKeyPaint
EighthWhite1:
    inc [x]
    jmp EighthWhiteKeyPaintBig
EighthWhite2:
    inc [y]
    mov [x],281
    jmp EighthWhiteKeyPaintBig
endp EighthWhiteKeyPaint

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proc FirstBlackKeyPaint
    mov [color3],00008h; Dark Gray Color
FirstBlackKeyPaint1:
    call PrintBlackKey1
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color3],00008h
    je ChangeToBlack1
    mov [color3],00008h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToBlack1:
    mov [color3],0000h
    call FirstBlackKeyPaint1
endp FirstBlackKeyPaint

; --------------------------
proc SecondBlackKeyPaint
    mov [color3],00008h; Dark Gray Color
SecondBlackKeyPaint1:
    call PrintBlackKey2
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color3],00008h
    je ChangeToBlack2
    mov [color3],00008h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToBlack2:
    mov [color3],0000h
    call SecondBlackKeyPaint1
endp SecondBlackKeyPaint

; --------------------------

proc ThirdBlackKeyPaint
    mov [color3],00008h; Dark Gray Color
ThirdBlackKeyPaint1:
    call PrintBlackKey3
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color3],00008h
    je ChangeToBlack3
    mov [color3],00008h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToBlack3:
    mov [color3],0000h
    call ThirdBlackKeyPaint1
endp ThirdBlackKeyPaint     
; --------------------------
proc FourthBlackKeyPaint
    mov [color3],00008h; Dark Gray Color
FourthBlackKeyPaint1:
    call PrintBlackKey4
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color3],00008h
    je ChangeToBlack4
    mov [color3],00008h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToBlack4:
    mov [color3],0000h
    call FourthBlackKeyPaint1
endp FourthBlackKeyPaint
; --------------------------

proc FifthBlackKeyPaint
    mov [color3],00008h; Dark Gray Color
FifthBlackKeyPaint1:
    call PrintBlackKey5
    mov  cx, 6h
    mov  dx, 4240h
    mov  ah, 86h
    int  15h
    cmp [color3],00008h
    je ChangeToBlack5
    mov [color3],00008h
    call ReceiveKey
ChangeToBlack5:
    mov [color3],0000h
    call FifthBlackKeyPaint1
endp FifthBlackKeyPaint     
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
    call graphic 
    call ReceiveKey
    
; --------------------------
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: I see that you use `int 15h Ah=86h` in DOSBox. In the past I have had nothing but troubles with it. Read about that [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/a-low-tech-approach-to-measuring-game-speed). Just maybe your problem is related?

Answer (score 1):

*after the key is pressed on the keyboard, the note turns gray and after 0.746 seconds it turns back white.*

It waits exactly as you have instructed your program in `proc FirstBlackKeyPaint` with [Int 15/AH=86h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1525.htm)

The flickering/glitching appears when a key is pressed for longer time. The keycode is then stored repeatedly to the keyboard buffer at typematic rate and it is retrieved in `proc ReceiveKey` by [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) several times, although the keyboard key was already released.
You could flush the buffer before each `ReceiveKey` with DOS service [Int 21/AH=0Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2567.htm):

```
ReceiveKey: 
 ;   mov ah,0
 ;   Int 16h
    MOV AH,0Ch  ; FLUSH BUFFER AND READ STANDARD INPUT
    MOV AL,01h  ; CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE
    INT 21h
```

However, you might want to generate tones with variable length, and in that case you will need a different input method: direct input from keyboard port 60h instead of BIOS service Int 16h. My DOS utility [OPIN Keys](http://vitsoft.info/opin.htm) can be used to learn what codes are read from keyboard port when keys are being pressed and released.